# Elevated installer with elevated custom action does not elevate executable

Tags: c#, .net, wix, installation

I have an installer with `InstallPrivileges="elevated"`. I include inside the file table an app.EXE

```
  <Component Id="myapp" Guid="*">
    <File Id="myapp" Source="myapp.exe"/>
  </Component>
```

using these CA to run it in an elevcated state:

```
<CustomAction Id="SetProp" Property="Launch" Value ="&quot;[INSTALLDIR]myapp.exe&quot;"/>
<CustomAction Id="Launch" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec64" Execute="deferred" Return="ignore" Impersonate="no"/>
```

scheduled like this:

```
  <Custom Action="SetProp" Before="Launch">NOT Installed</Custom>
  <Custom Action="Launch" Before="InstallFinalize">NOT Installed</Custom>
```

but according to Uachelper class (c#) and the missing result this process is not elevated BUT verbose log and myapp.exe log shows no error.

I also tried to use a type 2 custom action (binarykey etc.), a type 18 custom action (filekey etc.) and to include an app.manifest into myapp.exe with requiredadministrator.

nothing worked to elevate myapp.exe.. during installation.

Workaround I found is to start myapp.exe manually after installation completed (go to [INSTALLDIR] and doubleclick myapp.exe, will prompt uac etc.) but I want to avoid that.
I also thought about trying to use `runas` but am not sure if this would work or if this is feasible.

All of this is based on http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/qtexec.html , https://stackoverflow.com/a/10028939/4096653 and many more questions here on SO.

What am I missing or what else can I try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default a custom action will be elevated only if it is deferred, not impersonated, and sequenced between InstallInitialize and InstallFinalize, and if it's a per machine install, and then it will run elevated with the system account. Whether it will actually work or not depends on whether the code is prepared to deal with being aware that it's not running as the interactive user with access to HKCU, user profile items like PersonalFolder, and the code knows where its data is. When a custom action executable gets fired off it is via the CreateProcess() type of call (NOT a shell execute call) and so there is no UAC dialog/manifest checking stuff going on. So your WiX posted looks correct if you are deferred and before InstallFinalize. I have no idea what a UACHelper class thinks if are running as system and elevated. ProcessMonitor/Explorer might tell you what your rights/tokens are.

It should work if you create an impersonated launcher custom action that does an explicit Shell Execute of your exe, because that behaves like a run from Explorer by the interactive user. It will run the app which will then ask for elevation as long as the user doing the install is admin. In code that's something like ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute=true, ShellExecute() Win32.

If you need an impersonated CA to be elevated the MSI needs to be running as administrator or started from a program with an elevation manifest that then runs the MSI.

You'll see lots of advice (I hope) saying you should arrange to run this automatically the first time your app runs, just have it launched and remember whether that it has been run. Running as elevated user from an MSI is too complicated unless you have an elevated launching bootstrapper.

Comment: To clarify: I have all requirements for an elevated CA and my MSI also is run as admin. But even so type 2, type 18 CA and quiet exec does not work to elevate myapp.exe. To have this elevated as the current user (and not system account) I must create another elevatd CA which will call a Launcher application  . This launcher app will then call myapp.exe using shellexecute prompting the current user weith an UAC windows. Have I understood it correct?

Comment: That sounds correct - it should be fairly easy to do a sanity check, and you'll need to decide if the entire install should continue when your launcher is finished or if the launching CA should wait.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want this to run in Execute sequence and have scheduled your custom actions in InstallExecuteSequence

It might be so that your app is not able to run as Local system user so try to switch the Impersonate to yes `Impersonate="Yes"`