# Accessing variable in Wix CustomAction ExecCommand

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have a custom action in my WiX script to copy installation log:

```
<CustomAction Id="CopyLogFile" Execute="immediate"
            ExeCommand="cmd /c copy [MsiLogFileLocation] &quot;\&quot;[APPLICATIONFOLDER]Install.log\&quot;&quot;"
            Directory="TARGETDIR"
            Impersonate="no"
            Return="asyncNoWait" />
    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="CopyLogFile" OnExit="success" />
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

The problem is the APPLICATIONFOLDER environment variable.  No matter how I try to use it it does not work.  I tried single &quot, double &quot, no &quot, etc.  Nothing helps.

If I hard-code the destination like this:

```
ExeCommand="cmd /c copy [MsiLogFileLocation] c:\temp\Install.log"
```

it works fine.

However, I need to copy the install log to some known location on the user's machine.

I looked at [WiX CustomAction ExeCommand failing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028598/wix-customaction-execommand-failing), and [Not able to send Wix SourceDir path with spaces to custom action ExeCommand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696602/not-able-to-send-wix-sourcedir-path-with-spaces-to-custom-action-execommand) but it does not help with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Windows Installer Formatted reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368609(v=vs.85).aspx) your commandline should be:

```
cmd /c copy [MsiLogFileLocation] &quot;\&quot;[%APPLICATIONFOLDER]Install.log\&quot;&quot;
                                               ^
```

You are missing the `%` prefix for environment variables.